# Spark streaming using TextBlob for sentiment analysis

Tags: apache-spark, twitter, nlp

I am fairly new to Spark . starting my first project . Need to analyze the twitter data for sentiment analysis . I need to use TextBlob library in Python for doing it . 
I am able to get the twitter data and have the Dstream created after all necessary transformation . I am facing challange as how  to make the dstream data available ( which is having the tweet text) to the TextBlob  for analysis , as TextBlob  accepts only string value . How can i get the dstream value into TextBlob  for sentiment analysis. Any pointers is highly appreciated .

Thanks , 
Kary

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far? we can't code from scratch for you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this link: https://www.edureka.co/blog/spark-streaming ? Its pretty self explanatory. I hope you will be able to google out the python counterparts of scala code given in the post.... Happy Sparking!

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried using textblob for streaming dataset and wrote a small function to convert tweets to text and apply Textblob.
so you may write somethin glike this :

```
def getSentiment(self, text):
        sentiment = TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity
         if sentiment > float(benchmark):
            return float(positive)
        elif sentiment < float(benchmark):
            return float(negative)
        else:
            return float(noresponse)
```

and then write UDF that accepts the text

```
sentiment_score_udf = F.udf(lambda x: obj.getSentiment(x), FloatType())
```

here F is pyspark sql functions
and then you may use beow to calculate the sentiment score

```
sentiment_score_udf(col("value")).alias("sentiment_score")
```

hope this helps